# Spacemacs modeline color mismatch

Tags: spacemacs, themes, colors, configuration-files

Problems with my modeline separator aren't quite the *"Ugly separators"* problem as [seen here](http://boyanangelov.com/spacemacs/doc/DOCUMENTATION.html#orgheadline65). But the color is slightly off, as in this screenshot.

[image]

I can solve it with this piece of code. But then everything just looks more drab.

```
(setq ns-use-srgb-colorspace nil)
```

Is there a way of fixing the modeline color skew while keeping a full color pallette (or srgb-colorspace)? This is the [color balance](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs#automatic-update-on-master-branch) I expect to have.

Comment: what operating system are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using OSX, the modeline doesn't display correctly due to a bug with [srgb](https://github.com/milkypostman/powerline/issues/54). The if you don't want to set srgb to nil you should use [emacs-mac](https://github.com/railwaycat/homebrew-emacsmacport), a osx-friendly version by Mitsuharu Yamamoto.

You can also do this: `(setq powerline-default-separator 'utf-8)`

If you're not on OSX, then there is a similar srgb problem for your operating system and you'll likely just have to live with it or switch your separators.

Comment: _**emacs-mac**_ works like a charm. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use emacs-mac this will fix your problem
`(setq powerline-image-apple-rgb t)`

as suggested [here](https://github.com/milkypostman/powerline/issues/54#issuecomment-331265490)

Comment: Please summarize the info at that link, in addition to providing the link. Explain how/why that `setq` sexp fixes the problem. (Link-only answers are likely to be deleted.)